# .htaccess conditional application of rules and error redirection

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I'm looking to put a web application in production and I was wondering a few things about htaccess.

Here is my htaccess (the default htaccess provided by Zend Framework) :

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I would have liked to add two things in there, first a condition based on the **APPLICATION_ENV** to force SSL connection, but only in **production** (other possible values are development, testing and staging). The other thing I would have liked to set up is a redirection to the corresponding error action in the error controller based on the HTTP request error number.

I am not looking for a full answer, but at least where I need to start to be able to achieve my goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [mod_rewrite cheatsheet](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html) and [environment variable debugging HowTo](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html) for starters (nice supplement to the rather-sparse [Apache mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), IMHO).

Your solution to the production/https task may look a bit like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:APPLICATION_ENV} ^production$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: I have yet to try it on my Production server, but so far, with the little knowledge i have on htaccess, it makes sense